# Series continuity at one point - prove continuity at all points

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I'm struggling with an assignment on function continuity. I'm asked to show two things:

> **Part A)** Let $f:R\rightarrow R$ be a function where $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y \in R$
>
> I'm asked to prove that if $f$ is continuous at $x_0=0$ then $f$ is
>   continuous at **all** points $x_0 \in R$

I'm rather at a loss here. For the first part (A), we see that

$$||f(x_0)-f(x)||=||f(x_0 + (x-x_0))-f(x_0)||=||f(x_0)f(x-x_0)-f(x_0)||$$

Continuity at $x_0$ implies that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that when

$$||x-x_0||<\delta \rightarrow ||f(x)-f(x_0)||<\epsilon$$

I know this holds for $x_0=0$ but I don't see how this helps to prove general continuity?

> **Part B)** Let $g:R \rightarrow R$ with $g(xy)=g(x)+g(y)$. And I'm similarly to prove that if $g$ is contious at $x_0=1$ then it is
>   continous for all $x_0>0$

I suspect this second part will be elucidated, if I manage to understand the first, so I'll let this rest for now. Noting only that
$$||g(x)-g(x_0)||=||g\big(x_0\frac{x}{x_0}\big)-g(x_0)||=||g(x_0)+g(\frac{x}{x_0})-g(x_0)||=||g(\frac{x}{x_0})||$$

But again I'm not sure how this leads to continuity at all $x_0>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Note that for both questions, $f \equiv 0$ and $g \equiv 0$ are possible solutions, in which then they are clearly continuous. If $f \not\equiv 0$, then $f(0) = 1$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$, and choose $\delta$ such that $|x| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|f(x_0)|}$. We then have $|x - x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x - x_0) - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|f(x_0)|}$. Following your working:

\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(x_0)| = |f(x_0)f(x - x_0) - f(x_0)| = |f(x_0)||f(x - x_0) - 1| < \epsilon
\end{align*}

For part b), you have $g(1) = 0$ if $g \not\equiv 0$. The working is very similar, so you can try it out yourself.

Comment: I can follow the part of $|x| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|f(x_0)|}$, as this is simply continuity at $x_0=0$ with a rewritten norm.

However, I don't see how you get "$|x - x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x - x_0) - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|f(x_0)|}$".

The relation holds for $x_0=0$ that $|f(x)-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{|f(x_0)}$, but how does that translate to holding for any $x_0$? might not $|f(x-x_0)-1|$ be greater than $|f(x)-1|$?

Comment: For that, I am simply substituting $x$ with $x - x_0$, so it does not matter which $x_0$ it is to start with.

Comment: But the form $|f(x) - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|f(x_0)|}$ was derived for the specific case of $x_0=0$ where I knew, from the assignment, that $f$ was continuous. Maybe I'm just too hazy on the theory/definition, but I don't see how something derived for a specific $x_0=0$ translates to working for any $x-x_0$?

Comment: You seem to be distracted/confused by $x_0$ being there, when in fact it does not matter. Try seeing it from this angle: Substitute $y := x - x_0$. Then, as stated in the earlier part of the comment, you agree that $|y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(y) - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|f(x_0)|}$. Now substitute back $y$ with $x - x_0$, and my claim follows.

Comment: Indeed I am confused. It's true for $x_0=0$ the relation $|f(x)-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{|f(x_0)|}|$ holds (let's call it Equation 0). I agree, and I showed/understood that perfectly well. So far so good. But you're saying that if I choose some $x-x_0$ for *any* $x_0$ whatsoever, then Equation 0 still holds, with the slight adjustment of $f(x-x_0$ replacing the simple $f(x)$. That's the confusing bit; I use knowledge of the function about $x_0=0$ to find a relation, which then holds for any $x_0$ whatsoever?

Comment: More precisely, for any $x_0$ that we chose, if $|x - x_0| < \delta$, then $|f(x - x_0) - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|f(x_0)|}$. What is important is that it is the same $x - x_0$ in the $\delta$ range and in $f$. For instance, if $x = \frac{\delta}{2}$, then $|f(x) - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|f(x_0)|}$ as $\frac{\delta}{2} < \delta$. Similarly, if $x - x_0 = \frac{\delta}{2}$, then $|f(x - x_0) - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|f(x_0)|}$ as $\frac{\delta}{2} < \delta$.

Answer (score 0):

By putting $x=0=y$ we have
$$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y) \implies f(0)=f^2(0) \implies f(0)=0 ~or~ 1.$$
By putting $y=0$, we get $f(x)=f(x) f(0)= f(x)$, thus $f(0)=1$.

Next, the right limit of $f(x)$ as $h\rightarrow 0$  $$f(0^+)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(0+h)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(0)f(h)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(h) ~~~~~~~(1)$$
Smilarly the left limit
$$f(0^-)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(0-h)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(0)f(-h)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(-h) ~~~~~~~(2)$$
Given that $f(x)$ is cntinuous at $x=0$, then
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(h) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(-h)=f(0)=1~~~~~~~(3)$$
Let us show the continuity at any real number  $x=a$
$$f(a^+)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(a+h) = f(a)\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(h)=f(a)~~~from~~(3)$$
Dimilarly the left limit
$$f(a^-)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(a-h) = f(a)\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(-h)=f(a)~~~from~~(3)$$
This shows that the function is continuous at any real non zero value of $x$ provided iy is
continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, which demonstrates the issue very well. Sadly this particular assignment belongs to a section of our notebook that comes before "limits of functions" - in other words, I am expected to solve it without using knowledge of limits --- Sadly.

But I appreciate it nonetheless. It's a rather elegant solution.